# plus 100 with the last ip address

Tags: linux, shell

I have a list of ip address in the foo.txt,like this:
`192.168.0.10

192.168.0.11

192.168.0.12

...`
Now i want to ping them like this:
`ping -c 2 192.168.0.110

ping -c 2 192.168.0.111

...`
that means the last number of ip in foo.txt plus 100.
How can i write a shell script to do this automaticly.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." };
      { system("ping -c 2 "  $1 "." $2 "." $3 "." $4+100) }' foo.txt
```

This separates the string by ".", then uses system to make the system call with the command and adds 100 to the last octet.

Comment: How can i pick up the ip after adds 100 to the last octet? I have other use to that ip.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable and reuse it. Something like: `awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." }; { ip =  $1 "." $2 "." $3 "." $4+100; print("ping -c 2 " ip); } ' input.txt`